# Add a custom field in a custom content element by TYPO3 ver. 10.4.21

Tags: image, typo3, field, media

I hope anyone can help me to add a custom field for media&image element.

I create a custom content element with a extension "sitepackage builder".
I want to add a field for a media element with my new variable.

I want to add like this:

[image]

**The media element should be able to upload images (e.g. jpeg, png) and audio (mp3, mp4...). It's goot if I can also add other types of media like pdf and so on which are on the picture.**

I know how I can add a media element with "assets" in TCA, but then I can't use my variable.

I added two fields in TCA, a filed for media and another one for image. But then I need two variables for them. I want to use just a variable for a field which has medias and images.

This is my field for media now:

```
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['columns'] = array_replace_recursive(
    $GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['columns'],
    [
        'tx_pagesaddfields_slider1_video2' => array(
            'exclude' => 1,
            'label' => 'Video',
            'config' => \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::getFileFieldTCAConfig(
                    'tx_pagesaddfields_slider1_video2',
                    array(
                            'foreign_types' => array(
                                    \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\File::FILETYPE_AUDIO => array(
                                            'showitem' => '
                                                    --palette--;;audioOverlayPalette,
                                                    --palette--;;filePalette',
                                    ),
                                    \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\File::FILETYPE_VIDEO => array(
                                            'showitem' => '
                                                    --palette--;;videoOverlayPalette,
                                                    --palette--;;filePalette',
                                    )
                            )
                    ),
                    'wav,mpeg,mp4,ogg'
            )
    )
    ]
);
```

[image]

And this is my field for image now:

```
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['columns'] = array_replace_recursive(
    $GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['columns'],
    [
        'tx_pagesaddfields_slider1_image2' => [
            'exclude' => 1,
            'label' => 'Image',
            'config' => \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::getFileFieldTCAConfig(
                'tx_pagesaddfields_slider1_image2',
                [
                    'appearance' => [
                        'createNewRelationLinkTitle' => 'LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xlf:images.addFileReference'
                    ],
                    'overrideChildTca' => [
                        'columns' => [
                            'crop' => [
                                'description' => 'field description',
                            ],
                        ],
                        'types' => [
                            \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\File::FILETYPE_IMAGE => [
                                'showitem' => '
                                --palette--;;imageoverlayPalette,
                                --palette--;;filePalette'
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
                $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['GFX']['imagefile_ext']
            ),
        ],
    ]
);
```

[image]

Like I've already said, I want to add just one field for media & image like this:

[image]

I've searched a lot, but I can't find the codes for that.

If you know how you can add a custom field for media&image, please answer here.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at `typo3/sysext/frontend/Configuration/TCA/tt_content.php`

```
'assets' => [
        'label' => 'LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/Database.xlf:tt_content.asset_references',
        'config' => \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::getFileFieldTCAConfig('assets', [
            'appearance' => [
                'createNewRelationLinkTitle' => 'LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/Database.xlf:tt_content.asset_references.addFileReference'
            ],
            // custom configuration for displaying fields in the overlay/reference table
            // behaves the same as the image field.
            'overrideChildTca' => [
                'types' => [
                    '0' => [
                        'showitem' => '
                            --palette--;;imageoverlayPalette,
                            --palette--;;filePalette'
                    ],
                    \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\File::FILETYPE_TEXT => [
                        'showitem' => '
                            --palette--;;imageoverlayPalette,
                            --palette--;;filePalette'
                    ],
                    \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\File::FILETYPE_IMAGE => [
                        'showitem' => '
                            --palette--;;imageoverlayPalette,
                            --palette--;;filePalette'
                    ],
                    \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\File::FILETYPE_AUDIO => [
                        'showitem' => '
                            --palette--;;audioOverlayPalette,
                            --palette--;;filePalette'
                    ],
                    \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\File::FILETYPE_VIDEO => [
                        'showitem' => '
                            --palette--;;videoOverlayPalette,
                            --palette--;;filePalette'
                    ],
                    \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\File::FILETYPE_APPLICATION => [
                        'showitem' => '
                            --palette--;;imageoverlayPalette,
                            --palette--;;filePalette'
                    ]
                ],
            ],
        ], $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SYS']['mediafile_ext'])
    ],
```